# Foreaching data in json

Tags: php, laravel

```
  $data = []; // new array

    foreach ($availableSeat as $key => $value) {
        $data[]['id'] = $value['seat_name'];
    }

    return $data;
```

the image below is my JSON data, I am able to pull the seat_name value and change the name to "ID:, how can i loop the ID field and change the name to "vaule' with the foreach i have above?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0hOe.png)

Comment: Please **do not** paste code samples as a picture. StackOverflow is a place for people, who can read.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood what you need, but it sounds like you want to do this:

```php
$data = [];
foreach ($availableSeat as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = [
            'id' => $value['seat_name'],
            'value' => $value['id']
           ];
}

return $data;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! sorry for the misunderstanding description! but exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: @TesterMesster please mark this answer as accepted as long as it solves your problem, so the question will be considered as solved.